python pynput how to listen to a hotkey and single key simultaneously?
I have a hotkey set up with pynput:
hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
    keyboard.HotKey.parse('<alt>+b'),
    on_activate=on_activate
)

# Function to handle canonical form for key events
def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(hotkey_listener.canonical(k))

with keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
    on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)
) as hotkey_listener:
    hotkey_listener.join()

This works, but every time I need to cancel the script and update the code, I'd need to restart the kernel. I'd love to also have a key listerner on 'Esc', where upon pressing 'Esc', the script will clean up all listeners and exit.
I'm wondering how to do this in a way that's thread safe and not confusing? In my on_activate function, I have things like time.sleep() which can make things awkward in threading I think.

If you want a way that makes the code simple, you can use the module keyboard in addition to pynput. I think it's easiest to use keyboard.add_hotkey() in order to detect the press of the key 'esc'. Here's the main code:
#code before hotkey_listener.join(), including 'import keyboard'
hotkey_listener.join()
keyboard.add_hotkey('esc', lambda: stop_listener(hotkey_listener)) #add callback function when 'esc' is pressed

And here's the code for the stop_listener() function:
def stop_listener(listener):
    listener.stop() #stop the listener thread

Edit: The reason I chose to have a separate stop_listener() function instead of just stopping the listener in the lambda is because I think it is better to have a separate function, in case you need to execute something after the listener thread is stopped or if you want to make the code more readable. If you want, you can just pile everything into the lambda, or include code after the with statement.
